# virtual box doesn't work on ubuntu 16.10 VT-x problm

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, virtualization

after installing virtualBox in Ubuntu 16.10 in my thinkpad x201 laptop I tried to load an Ubuntu 16.4 x86 VM on it , in a regular user when I click on Start button to run the VM it shows me a popup windows with this message:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEiMQ.png)

```
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMX_DISABLED).

Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

I checkout my BIOS setting but VT-x was enabled already , after surfing the web for this problem I find out my regular user is not a member of vboxusers and perhaps thats why it doesn't work , so I add my regular user as a member to this group

```
sudo gpasswd -a kave vboxusers
```

after that when I click on the start button the result is same as above then I ran virtualbox as super user

```
sudo virtualbox
```

then again I create a new VM with root permissions and it works well !

my question is why virtualbox doesn't work with a regular user ?

Comment: Did you reboot after adding yourself to the group?

Comment: @Terrance  yes I did .

Comment: You did verify that you are part of the vboxusers after the reboot, correct?  `groups` from the command line.

Comment: yes I do

kave@KC:~$ groups
kave adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxusers